# LaTeXiT in Evernote

Tags: macos, mac, hotkeys, latex, evernote

I was following [this thread](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/20977-evernote-and-latexit-services/) because I'm a college student studying physics, and taking notes in LaTeX format is really important for me, when I saw that I could use LaTeX in EN (Evernote) by just installing LaTeXiT, and then doing these commands:

highlight the text, right-click it, go to services, and click on "Typeset LaTeX text".

I have some experience programming in some languages and using the terminal on Mac, and I thought it would be a simple and rewarding exercise to create something that could make this a bit easier for me.

What I have in mind is something that is, ideally, some sort of hotkey that runs the "Typeset LaTeX text" on any highlighted text. The problem is, I don't even know where to begin on such a project. I know there are ways to make custom hotkeys, but how would I make one that does something so specific?

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, really easily.

You just go to the apple button at the top-left
Go to System Preferences
Keyboard
Shortcuts
In the left, click on Services
Click on typeset LaTeX text and then do the command you want.
[Make sure the command isn't used inside of the app](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10714) while you have text selected